# Huawei backup not offering location "Internal storage"

Tags: backup, huawei

I want do backup a Huawei P20 lite using its own "Backup" app. But it does not offer "Internal storage" as a backup location, even if it supports that, according to documentation here: [PHONE BACKUP AND RESTORE GUIDE](https://consumer.huawei.com/en/support/recycling/data-backup/) (see second screenshot there)

There is 44 GB of internal storage free (of 64GB total).

What is wrong?

I want to do a backup in the most hassle free way possible. There is no SD card at hand and have the slot used for the second SIM anyway.

Comment: Apparently this feature was removed in a recent version. Can anyone confirm? It is still listed in the settings part of the app.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that the option to backup to internal storage is not available on the recent Huawei Backup application version 8.02.xxx.

You can still install the older versions of the application available on [APKmirror](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/huawei-internet-services/huawei-backup/)  (versions 7.0.xxx) if you want  to back up on internal storage:

[image]

<sup>online image</sup>

Comment: Actually, the April 8.0.3xx version also still has it. I'll gather some more details and maybe add it to your answer.

Comment: ok thanks, on my device I keep using version 7.0xxx , yesterday thats when I tested with the new version and found out indeed the option has been removed, so I downgraded to my usual old version